# pandas.Series.div() vs /=

Tags: python, pandas, performance

I'm curious why pandas.Series.div() is slower than /= when applying to a pandas Series of numbers. For example:

```
python3 -m timeit -s 'import pandas as pd; ser = pd.Series(list(range(99999)))' 'ser /= 7'
1000 loops, best of 3: 584 usec per loop

python3 -m timeit -s 'import pandas as pd; ser = pd.Series(list(range(99999)))' 'ser.div(7)'
1000 loops, best of 3: 746 usec per loop
```

I assume that it's because the former changes the series in place whereas the latter returns a new Series. But if that's the case, then why bother implementing div() and mul() at all if they're not as fast as /= and */?
Even if you don't want to change the series in place, ser / 7 is still faster than .div():

```
python3 -m timeit -s 'import pandas as pd; ser = pd.Series(list(range(99999)))' 'ser / 7'
1000 loops, best of 3: 656 usec per loop
```

So what is the use of pd.Series.div() and what about it makes it slower?

Comment: For one, they support a `fill_value` argument, making it much simpler to do `s1.add(s2, fill_value=0)` instead of filling the NaN with 0 first in both.

Comment: Also, while for a scalar that seems to be the case, see what happens when you do `ser+ser` as opposed to `ser.add(ser)`. I get the latter is faster.

Comment: @ALollz about your second comment, you can't really compare ser.add(ser) to ser+ser because the former is done in place whereas the latter returns a new series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pandas `.div` obviously implement division similarly to `/` and `/=`.

The main reason to have a separate `.div` is that Pandas embraces a syntax model where operations on dataframes are described by the applications of consecutive *filters*, e.g. `.div`, `.str`, etc. which allows for simple concatenations:

```py
ser.div(7).apply(lambda x: 'text: ' + str(x)).str.upper()
```

as well as simpler support for multiple arguments (cfr. `.func(a, b, c)` would not be possible to write with a binary operator).

By contrast, the same would have been written without `div` as:

```py
(ser / 7).apply(lambda x: 'text: ' + str(x)).str.upper()
```

The `/` operation may be faster because there is less Python overhead associated with `/` operator compared to `.div()`.

By contrast, the `x /= y` operator replaces the construct `x = x / y`.
For vectorized containers based on NumPy (like Pandas), it goes a little beyond that: it uses an **in-place** operation instead of creating a (potentially time- and memory-consuming) copy of `x`. This is the reason why `/=` is faster than both `/` and `.div()`.

Note that, while in most cases this is equivalent, sometimes (like in this case) it may still require conversion to a different data type, which is done automatically in Pandas (but not in NumPy).